# Filter the data based on search input of image name

Tags: javascript, html

```
I am trying to filter out based on search by name but problem in code.
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Products" id="filter_products"/>
            <!-- <ul id="users-list"></ul> -->
            <div class="row" id="products">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../img/scenery.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
                        <div class="card_body">
                            <ul id="products-list"><h2 class="card-title" id="scenery">Scenery</h2></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul><div class="price">Rs. 150/- </div></ul>
                            <!-- <a href="../html/register.html"><input type="submit" name="" value="Order Now"></a> -->
                            <a href="../html/register.html">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md">Order Now</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../img/photo_frame-1.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
                        <div class="card_body">
                            <ul id="products-list"><h2 class="card-title" id="photoframe">Photo Frames</h2></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="price">Rs. 100/- </div>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="../html/register.html">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md">Order Now</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../img/gift-2.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
                        <div class="card_body">
                            <ul id="products-list"><h2 class="card-title" id="gift">Gifts</h2></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="price">Rs. 100/- </div>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="../html/register.html">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md">Order Now</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="products">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../img/toys.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
                        <div class="card_body">
                            <ul id="products-list"><h2 class="card-title" id="toys">Toys & Games</h2></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="price">Rs. 200/- </div>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="../html/register.html">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md">Order Now</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                


Here is my Javascript code snippet which has problem.

const search = document.getElementById("filter_products");
console.log(search);
const productName = document.querySelectorAll(".card_body .card-title");

search.addEventListener("keyup", filterProducts);

function filterProducts(e) 
{
    const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    productName.forEach(function(product) 
    {
        const item = product.firstChild.textContent;
                
        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) 
        {
            product.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "block"
        }
        else 
        {
            product.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is that when i am trying to search any item the filter is not working. It show undefined error.Therefore the problem is persisting and i am trying various method but still not get the correct solutions which can works for me. So that the whole issue.I am trying to make my search box, filter through several images on my website. So if I type scenery into the search box, it not show that item.

Comment: It's working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/debnathrajdeep/rjydwm56/

Comment: when searching for particular item the other items are not hiding. I want the product item that i searched should only be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me..

Make sure your JS is included in your html either putting it between "script" tags like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Products" id="filter_products"/>
            <!-- <ul id="users-list"></ul> -->
            <div class="row" id="products">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../img/scenery.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
                        <div class="card_body">
                            <ul id="products-list"><h2 class="card-title" id="scenery">Scenery</h2></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul><div class="price">Rs. 150/- </div></ul>
                            <!-- <a href="../html/register.html"><input type="submit" name="" value="Order Now"></a> -->
                            <a href="../html/register.html">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md">Order Now</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../img/photo_frame-1.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
                        <div class="card_body">
                            <ul id="products-list"><h2 class="card-title" id="photoframe">Photo Frames</h2></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="price">Rs. 100/- </div>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="../html/register.html">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md">Order Now</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../img/gift-2.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
                        <div class="card_body">
                            <ul id="products-list"><h2 class="card-title" id="gift">Gifts</h2></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="price">Rs. 100/- </div>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="../html/register.html">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md">Order Now</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="products">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-10 d-block m-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../img/toys.jpg" class="card-img img-fluid">
                        <div class="card_body">
                            <ul id="products-list"><h2 class="card-title" id="toys">Toys & Games</h2></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="price">Rs. 200/- </div>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="../html/register.html">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md">Order Now</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                


<script>

const search = document.getElementById("filter_products");
console.log(search);
const productName = document.querySelectorAll(".card_body .card-title");

search.addEventListener("keyup", filterProducts);

function filterProducts(e) 
{
    const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    productName.forEach(function(product) 
    {
        const item = product.firstChild.textContent;
                
        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) 
        {
            product.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "block"
        }
        else 
        {
            product.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

or by putting it into a separate js file and including it like this:

```
<script src="yourPath">
```

Comment: When searching for particular item the other items are not hiding. I want the product item that i searched should only be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code below, you need to go one more level up in `parentElement`

```
if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1) 
        {
            product.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "block"
        }
        else 
        {
            product.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"
        }
```